# Import API to GoogleSheets

Tags: json, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to run a script to import data into a GoogleSheet, but cannot seem to find an easy way to do this.

The API pull from the website comes out as;

curl -X GET "https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=19720" -H "accept: application/xml"

I'm not sure what to do with this. I have tried ImportHTML as well as other functions, but I believe this requires a script. Could someone help, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can I ask you about the values and/or the results you want?

Comment: It should result in a table with TypeID "19720" Max Buy Order "$$$" Average Buy Order "$$$" Volume "###"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted 2 samples, could you please confirm it? If those are not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I will try this shortly!

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for you? If your issue was not resolved, I have to think of the solution.

Comment: Good day, whenever I tried to implement this in the Google Sheets I ended up just getting an error in the cell.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about ``just getting an error in the cell.`` because in my environment, no error occurs. So in order to confirm correctly your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the URL, XML data can be retrieved. So how about these patterns using `IMPORTXML()`?

When you use this, at first, please put the URL of `https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=19720` to a cell "A1", and put the formula to other cell.

#### Pattern 1:

If you want to retrieve the values of "Max Buy Order", "Average Buy Order" and "Volume" in the order, as a simple sample, how about this?

```
={IMPORTXML(A1,"//buy/max"),IMPORTXML(A1,"//buy/avg"),IMPORTXML(A1,"//buy/volume")}
```

#### Pattern 2:

If you want to retrieve the values of "Max Buy Order", "Average Buy Order" and "Volume" without in the order (this means the order in XML data. So it's "Volume", "Average Buy Order" and "Max Buy Order".), how about this?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//buy/max | //buy/avg | //buy/volume")
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//buy/max | //buy/avg | //buy/volume"))
```

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)